# How to remove modules from blog item page

Tags: joomla, blogs

I have my joomla 3 homepage that is actually blog page. And it also has some modules assigned to it. When I click to open particular blog item (clicking read more button) I am redirected to that blog item page that also has those modules assigned and actually completely same look as home page.

What I want is to keep modules on my home blog page, and remove it from blog item page. I want my blog item page to have only that blog item content nad nothing more. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need some configuration **for each module**, go to your modules, inside you can see
 a tab called **Menu Assignment**, from here select for example show only on homepage.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but you did not understand. My homepage (frontpage) is category blog page. And it is assigned to "Home" item in Mainmenu. It means that it is default page. So I need to have some modules assigned to "Home" item in  modules menu assigment tab.

Comment: And there is no menu item for any particular blog item that I could use to follow your advice. I could make fake menu for blog items  but I do not want, because i do not want to make new manu items in that fake menu whenever I want to publish new item in the blog.

Comment: Hi, The screenshot is only an example for the Tab "Menu Assignment", go to each module and use this tab to assign each module to your menu item. In this case you already have the menu item, your menu item is your homepage with the category blog".

Comment: Anyway, I solved it in this way. I make new manu that I really called "fakemenu". And I make menu item of type "category blog" that points to my choosen category for homepage. And I did not publish this menu, but than, I got this new menu dispalyed in modules menu assignment tab and, off course, I keep this menuitem unchecked for all my modules.

Comment: In that way, I have my modules on my home page that show category blog, and when I click some blog item I get that item in new page without modules. I hope this will help other users too.